# Is it possible to get rid of radicals from this term?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have the following term:

$$ bx^2 -2abx + a^2b -2\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{c^2}}cdx + 2\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{c^2}}cda + c^2e - ex^2 - f $$

I am trying to remove the radicals from it, but I always end up in a dead end. Is it at all possible?

Comment: How is it related to linear algebra ?

Comment: @An_Elephant it is obviously wrong tag.

Comment: Why do you want to remove the radical?  In what context did this expression appear?

Comment: @CroCo Yes, I was telling OP through this question that the tag he selected is not matching with the question text.

Comment: If this expression is part of equation without radical in other part, you can rearrange terms to leave only radicals in one hand and factor out $\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{c^2}}$, then square both parts to eliminate radical.

Comment: Not sure what the context is, but the substitution $x = c \sin t$ comes to mind if you're just looking for ideas.